# GeoServer REST API - when creating image mosaic from folder co-located with GeoServer, coverage layer not created

Tags: rest, geoserver

For processing performance reasons, (I run a process that creates the mosaic tiffs from other data) I am trying to create a time dimensioned imagemosaic from a folder of files co-located with GeoServer. I have been able to create the coverage store with a curl command like this ...

**`curl -v -u user:password XPOST -H "Content-type:application/xml" -d '<coverageStore><name>coveragestore_name</name><workspace>myworksp</workspace><type>ImageMosaic</type><url>file:time-series/sub-folder/sub-folder-with-tiffs-and-prop-files</url><enabled>true</enabled></coverageStore>' https://mygeoserver.domain.org/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores`**

Here is the developer logging for this 1st curl command:

```
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
2023-02-02 22:02:42,741 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores, QueryString: null with /rest/**
2023-02-02 22:02:42,773 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache has no entry for basic, admin:75456e223a05267a7b367f93d1784513
2023-02-02 22:02:42,799 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Did not send remember-me cookie (principal did not set parameter '_spring_security_remember_me')
2023-02-02 22:02:42,799 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.rememberme.GeoServerTokenBasedRememberMeServices] - Remember-me login not requested.
2023-02-02 22:02:42,799 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache adding new entry for basic, admin:75456e223a05267a7b367f93d1784513
2023-02-02 22:02:42,799 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 0
2023-02-02 22:02:42,801 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache added new entry for basic, admin:75456e223a05267a7b367f93d1784513
2023-02-02 22:02:42,801 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 1
2023-02-02 22:02:42,801 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores'; to: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores'  and httpMethod= POST
2023-02-02 22:02:42,802 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
2023-02-02 22:02:42,802 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
2023-02-02 22:02:42,802 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
2023-02-02 22:02:42,802 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
2023-02-02 22:02:42,802 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
2023-02-02 22:02:42,802 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - Testing /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores for monitor filtering
2023-02-02 22:02:42,815 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 locking in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:02:42,815 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 got the lock in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:02:42,915 TRACE [org.geoserver.config] - org.geoserver.catalog.event.impl.CatalogBeforeAddEventImpl@55092e01 :handlePreAddEvent
2023-02-02 22:02:42,916 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisting coverage store coveragestore_name
2023-02-02 22:02:42,937 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33 to workspaces/myworksp/coveragestore_name coveragestore.xml
2023-02-02 22:02:42,945 DEBUG [org.geoserver.config] - Persisted com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46 to global.xml
2023-02-02 22:02:42,947 INFO [org.geoserver.rest.catalog] - POST coverage store coveragestore_name
2023-02-02 22:02:42,965 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 locking in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:02:42,965 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:02:42,966 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

However it does not create the coverage layer as well.
I have tried many suggestions without success to create the coverage after the store is created.

This 2nd curl command seems to get the closest. It creates the DB table, and some more files in the sub-folder-with-tiffs-and-prop-files folder, but is does not create the coverage ...

**`curl -v -u user:password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file:///time-series/sub-folder/sub-folder-with-tiffs-and-prop-files"  https://mygeoserver.domain.org/geoserver/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic`**

Here is the developer logging for this 2nd curl command:

```
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/gwc/rest/web/**'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_check/'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/j_spring_security_logout/'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null'; against '/rest/**'
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic, QueryString: null with /rest/**
2023-02-02 22:05:26,484 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache found an entry for basic, admin:75456e223a05267a7b367f93d1784513
2023-02-02 22:05:26,485 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Converted URL to lowercase, from: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic'; to: '/rest/workspaces/adcirc_2023/coveragestores/4287-2022111118-namforecast_fort63_zeta/external.imagemosaic'  and httpMethod= POST
2023-02-02 22:05:26,485 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [GET]
2023-02-02 22:05:26,485 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=false
2023-02-02 22:05:26,485 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - ~~~~~~~~~~ antPath= /** methodList= [POST, DELETE, PUT]
2023-02-02 22:05:26,485 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - Candidate is: '/rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic'; antPath is /**; matchedPath=true; matchedMethods=true
2023-02-02 22:05:26,485 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.RESTfulPathBasedFilterInvocationDefinitionMap] - returning ADMIN
2023-02-02 22:05:26,486 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - Testing /rest/workspaces/myworksp/coveragestores/coveragestore_name/external.imagemosaic for monitor filtering
2023-02-02 22:05:26,487 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 98 locking in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:05:26,488 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 98 got the lock in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:05:27,383 WARN [org.geotools.jdbc] - Fetching fields from Database
2023-02-02 22:05:27,658 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:27,663 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 4ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:29,444 ERROR [org.geoserver.rest] - Failed to locate the input file file:time-series/sub-folder/sub-folder-with-tiffs-and-prop-files
org.geoserver.rest.RestException 400 BAD_REQUEST: Failed to locate the input file file:time-series/sub-folder/sub-folder-with-tiffs-and-prop-files
    at org.geoserver.rest.util.RESTUtils.handleEXTERNALUpload(RESTUtils.java:207)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.AbstractStoreUploadController.handleFileUpload(AbstractStoreUploadController.java:80)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.doFileUpload(CoverageStoreFileController.java:458)
    at org.geoserver.rest.catalog.CoverageStoreFileController.coverageStorePost(CoverageStoreFileController.java:121)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:144)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.flow.controller.IpBlacklistFilter.doFilter(IpBlacklistFilter.java:89)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1726)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2023-02-02 22:05:29,445 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 98 locking in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:05:29,445 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 98 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
2023-02-02 22:05:29,446 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2023-02-02 22:05:32,664 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:32,676 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 12ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:37,676 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:37,678 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 1ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:42,678 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - polling contents of /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:42,687 TRACE [org.geoserver.platform.resource] - delta computed in 9ms for /opt/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
2023-02-02 22:05:45,259 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 9-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&lines=1000'; against '/web/**'
2023-02-02 22:05:45,259 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 9-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&lines=1000 with /web/**
2023-02-02 22:05:45,260 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage for monitor filtering
2023-02-02 22:05:45,260 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage was filtered from monitoring
2023-02-02 22:05:45,261 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,262 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,262 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,262 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,262 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,262 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 locking in mode READ
2023-02-02 22:05:45,262 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 got the lock in mode READ
2023-02-02 22:05:45,264 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 locking in mode READ
2023-02-02 22:05:45,264 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 103 releasing the lock in mode READ
2023-02-02 22:05:45,267 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2023-02-02 22:05:45,307 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: lines=1000'; against '/web/**'
2023-02-02 22:05:45,307 DEBUG [org.geoserver.security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: lines=1000 with /web/**
2023-02-02 22:05:45,307 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - Testing /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage for monitor filtering
2023-02-02 22:05:45,307 DEBUG [org.geoserver.monitor] - /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.LogPage was filtered from monitoring
2023-02-02 22:05:45,311 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,311 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,311 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,311 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2023-02-02 22:05:45,311 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
```

I have spent many days trying to get this to work. Can anyone steer me in the right direction? Thanks very much!

**UPDATE:** Just realized maybe I should use file.imagemosaic instead of external.imagemosaic on the second curl command? This results in no errors, but the **coverage is still not created**!

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Thank you for your response @IanTurton . I have updated my post as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try PUT instead of POST in your curl request.